# Can I target multiple InfoPath forms to the same Sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am building a sharepoint site to track project progress.  Different teams are responsible for different aspects of the project, and I want to capture all of the progress data in one list, but have separate forms for each team.  Can different InfoPath form templates all update the same list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, you just deploy your Form as "Site Content Type" and then add the content type to your list (after enabling "Allow Management of Content Types in the Advanced Settings in your List).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create the list, add the different content types, then go to "form options" in the list settings.  That will let you customize an infopath form for each content type.